# Помогите разобраться с кодом Router

Tags: php, kohana

Очень прошу помощи. [core / classes / Kohana / Route.php](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Route.php)
Интересует метод `compile`.

```
    public static function compile($uri, array $regex = NULL)
{
// The URI should be considered literal except for keys and optional parts
// Escape everything preg_quote would escape except for : ( ) < >
$expression = preg_replace('#'.Route::REGEX_ESCAPE.'#', '\\\\$0', $uri);

if (strpos($expression, '(') !== FALSE)
{
// Make optional parts of the URI non-capturing and optional
$expression = str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('(?:', ')?'), $expression);
}

// Insert default regex for keys
$expression = str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('(?P<', '>'.Route::REGEX_SEGMENT.')'), $expression);

if ($regex)
{
$search = $replace = array();
foreach ($regex as $key => $value)
{
$search[] = "<$key>".Route::REGEX_SEGMENT;
$replace[] = "<$key>$value";
}

// Replace the default regex with the user-specified regex
$expression = str_replace($search, $replace, $expression);
}

return '#^'.$expression.'$#uD';
}
```

Помогите разобратся в первую очередь вот с этой строкой :

```
$expression = preg_replace('#'.Route::REGEX_ESCAPE.'#', '\\\\$0', $uri);
```

Как здесь происходит замена? И что это такое `\\\\$0`?

Буду очень рад? если прокомментируете код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь делается экранирование символов используемых в регулярных выражениях, кроме круглых и угловых скобок. Это позволяет в маршруте использовать, например, вопросительный знак или точку (см. Route::REGEXP_ESCAPE).

Чтобы узнать что такое `\\\\$0` лучше почитать про регулярные выражения и [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php):

> Для использования обратного слэша, его
> необходимо продублировать (строка PHP
> "`\\\\`")

Т.е., к тому, что нашли впереди добавляется обратный слеш.

Comment: А почему не используется стандартное решение: preg_quote ?

Comment: Подозреваю, что из-за того, что они не хотят экранировать некоторые из символов, которые экранирует ``preg_quote()``, например, ``<>()``. см. [``Route::REGEXP_ESCAPE``](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Route.php#L48)